# Most efficient way to set variable based on different results

Tags: function, powershell

I am running validations based on details about the machine the script is running on. I currently have an API that will return 1 of the following

```
Name1
Name1, Name2
Name1, Name3
Name1, Name2, Name3
Name2, Name3
Name2
Name3
```

What would be the most efficient way to run a different set of validations (functions) based upon one of those 7 results?

EDIT: Here is some pseudo code to represent what I am trying to accomplish. I am hoping to make the switch and values in the `where-object` of each switch cleaner

```
function returnRelevantBlankValues {
    $instance = $args[0] #could be any 7 of the strings above
    $inputFile = "C:\path\input.txt"
    $fileResults = "C:\path\output.txt"
    switch ($instance){
        "name1" {
            Get-Content $inputFile | where-object {
                $_ -like "*name1*" -and $_ -notlike "*name2*" -and $_ -notlike "*name3"} > $fileResults
        }
        "name1, name2" {
            Get-Content $inputFile | where-object {
                $_ -like "*name1*" -and $_ -like "*name1*" -and $_ -notlike "*name3"} > $fileResults
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what are you trying to achieve? Like some code.

Comment: Sure. will clean the code and put it up in a minute.

Comment: added some pseudo code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I validate based on a server's role, and a server can have more than one.

First I create server objects:

```
$servers = @()
$servers += New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
   Name = "Server1"
   Role = "DB"
}
$servers += New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
   Name = "Server2"
   Role = "DB","Application"
}
```

(In actuality I store them in XML, but this works)

Then, you can use the `$_.Role -contains "Application"` to determine if you want to run a check.  This also makes it easier to eventually add additional servers of similar roles.  YMMV depending on the details of what you're trying to check.

Comment: Would you use a `switch -wildcard` to call various functions based on what `$_.Role` contains?

Comment: No, because since I have multiple roles I want to hit multiple tests.  So I'd just use a series of ifs for each role type.